# How to model java.time.duration in Mysql Database

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee

I am writing a simple application to get to know Java EE, and I need to save an entity into my MySQL DB, which contains a `java.time.duration`.

What is the best way to store that?

Comment: Do you use JPA? Which provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, [JPA still does not support the types of the new `java.time` package](https://java.net/jira/browse/JPA_SPEC-63)

That said, you have a couple of methods (`toString` and `parse`) that provide you a way by converting to String; v.g.

```
@Transient
private Duration myDuration;

@Column(name="DURATION")
String myDurationString;

@PostLoad
public void init() {
  this.myDuration = this.myDurationString == null ? null : Duration.parse(this.myDurationString);
};

public Duration getMyDuration() {
  return this.myDuration;
}

public void setMyDuration(Duration _myDuration) {
  this.myDurationString = _myDuration == null ? null : _myDuration.toString();
}
```

Remember that you should not include getters and getters for `myDurationString`.

Optionally, you could use `toMillis()` and `ofMillis()`, if you are more comfortable with the number as milliseconds.

Comment: And, if you are using JPA 2.1, you could use the same logic in a `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`

Comment: Using toString() was my first guess as well, but since my duration can't be longer than 24h, I'll go with a BigInt and store the nanoseconds. Tanks for answering.

Comment: Link to java.net no longer working. Should be updated to https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/issues/63

Answer (score 5):

As Hibernate 4.3 supports JPA 2.1 you can use the [AttributeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) class:

```
@Converter
public class DurationToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Duration, String>
{

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Duration duration)
    {
        return duration == null ? null : duration.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Duration convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData)
    {
        return dbData == null ? null : Duration.parse(dbData);
    }
}

@Entity
public class Ent {

    @Column
    @Convert(DurationToStringConverter.class)
    Duration duration;

}
```

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html

Answer (score 1):

Integer type, length as required. Either use a static unit (i.e. milliseconds) or store the unit in a separate field - if you're using JPA2, it has enum to string mapping for this.

If you're using JPA 2.1, you can probably even use a `@Converter`, eliminating the need for conversion code in your entities.